# Angular Unit Test: Unknown provider: $$qProvider <- $$q <- $interval

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, dependency-injection, jasmine

I'm trying to set up unit tests for an existing Angular JS project, but I keep getting the error in the title:

```
Unknown provider: $$qProvider <- $$q <- $interval
```

Here is my unit test:

describe("screen controller", function(){

```
beforeEach(module('tsApp'));

var scope, createController, $interval, $timeout, $translate, $sce, $controller; 

beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, $rootScope, _$interval_, _$timeout_, _$translate_, _$sce_ ){

    // The injector unwraps the underscores (_) from around the parameter names when matching
    $interval = _$interval_;
    $timeout = _$timeout_;
    $translate = _$translate_;
    $sce = _$sce_;
    $controller = _$controller_;
    scope = $rootScope.$new();

    createController = function() {
      return $controller('screenCtrl', {
        '$scope' : scope,
        '$interval' : $interval,
        '$timeout' : $timeout,
        '$translate' : $translate,
        '$sce' : $sce
      });
    };
}));

describe('first test', function() {
    it('it runs without error!', function() {
      var controller = createController();
      expect(true).toEqual(true);
    });
});
```

});

And the controller I'm trying to test starts like this:

```
var screenCtrl = tsApp.controller('screenCtrl', function($scope, updateService, $translate, $sce, $interval, $timeout) {
```

I'm guessing there is something wrong with the dependancies I'm injecting. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think my problem comes from the fact that I do not understand what the second parameter of the `$controller()` function is doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$$qProvider` was introduced in AngularJS **1.3.0-beta.14**. It is undocumented and used internally.

Prior to this version `$IntervalProvider` used `$q` and in beta.14 and later it uses both `$q` and `$$q`.

Somewhere you have conflicting versions of AngularJS modules.

Check all your files or for example your Bower components.

Make sure your core AngularJS version is high enough for other modules you might be using. Angular Material for example requires Angular 1.3.x.

Comment: Thanks!! I have a hunch it's my version of angular-mocks.js which I downloaded recently. Is there a version of that somewhere which is compatible with angular 1.2.x? Or do I need to update my angular?

Comment: Go the folder corresponding with your version and get angular-mocks.js: https://code.angularjs.org/

Comment: Ah! I didn't know that was possible! Out of curiosity? Should I consider upgrading Angular? Are their breaking changes between 1.2 and 1.3?

Comment: Yes there are beaking changes. You can read about them here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration

Comment: That was it! Thanks for your help. BTW, I'm currently fumbling with a different issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28319879/angular-unit-testing-how-to-test-controller-properties-without-scope I suspect it might be an easy answer for you.

Comment: Wrote an answer. Hope it helps.